# Examples for fork without execv

Tags: operating-system

I'm taking Operating Systems course now, and was just introduced to the "fork", "execv" pair.

As to my understanding right now, fork is used to create an abstraction for process while execv is used to make that process do some actual work.

My intuition tells me that that is not that simple and there are some practical uses to only use "fork" without "execv".
Can you make an example for me?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems useless to have a child process that is completely same as its parent.But considering that you can separate its behavior using an if statement, it's possible to imagine uses for fork() itself.

As you know, fork() creates a new process.The new process is a duplicate of the original(parent) process with same code and same program counter but naturally different PCB.

Now let's see the example you're looking for.In many cases, we may need have multiprocessing.In this code we create particular number of processes to do some work for us.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#define PROCESS_NOM 5

int main()
{
    pid_t pid; //Or int pid
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < PROCESS_NOM; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1)
            printf("Error!\n");
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            //Child process code
            //Maybe manipulation data with parent using IPC
            //Of course you can call other functions here to execute in child process.
            exit(0);
        }
        //Since we have used exit() function inside if scope, other parts of main function will execute only for parent process.
    }
}
```

Fork returns process id of the new(child) process to the parent process. So in the parent process, pid gets a positive value.Concurrently in the child processes, there is a pid variable that gets nothing since they didn't call fork() and will assign to zero.

At the end, let me add this.There are other "exec family" system calls: execl(), execlp, etc. All of these functions replace the current process image(memory space) with a new process image.